# how to pass null & populated value through function to sql string

Tags: php

How can you pass a null value or populated value through function to SQL string...

```sql
SELECT id FROM dod WHERE department = 'OPS' AND dod_1 = '1'
    AND dod_2 = 'a' AND dod_3 = '3' AND dod_4 = '' AND dod_5 = ''
```

```php
function insertTable2Link($db, $var_1, $var_2 = NULL, $var_3 = NULL, $var_4 = NULL, $var_5 = NULL) {

    $query_select = pg_query($db, "SELECT id FROM abc WHERE dod_1 = '{$var_1}' AND dod_2 = '{$var_2}' AND dod_3 = '{$var_3}' AND dod_4 = '{$var_4}' AND dod_5 = '{$var_5}'");

}
```

In this example sometimes I need `dod_5 IS NULL` other times I need `dod_5 = '133'`.

Comment: what is deciding if you need 133 or null?

Comment: you would be better using a prepared statement with named parameters as this supports nulls. At least use pg_escape_string on the vars you have above as you are leaving yourself open to injection.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id FROM abc WHERE dod_1 = '{$var_1}' AND dod_2 = '{$var_2}' AND dod_3 = '{$var_3}' AND dod_4 = '{$var_4}' AND (dod_5 = '{$var_5}' OR dod_5 IS NULL);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass null value in database then you should do like this

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
  $name = $_POST["name"];
  if($_POST['age']==''){
     $data= 'NULL';
  }else{
     $data=$_POST["age"];
  }
  $ins="insert into demonull(`name`,`age`)values('".$name."','".$data."')";
  mysql_query($ins);
}
```